# Performance issues with jspdf + html2canvas if there are many pages

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

```
const data = document.getElementById('containerDiv')!;
html2canvas(data, {
  removeContainer: false
}).then((canvas:any) => {
  const imgWidth = 208;
  const pageHeight = 295;
  const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
  let heightLeft = imgHeight;
  let position = 0;
  heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  const doc = new jspdf('p', 'mm');
  doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
  while (heightLeft >= 0) {
    position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
    doc.addPage();
    doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  }
  doc.save('test.pdf');
});
```

Am facing performance issues with html2Canvas if there are multiple pages to render. Browser takes more time to download pdf and it get freezed.

Comment: @KJ am facing this issue on chrome browser. any other alternate library you can suggest supported with Angular ?

Comment: Have found a solution?